# swiftui does not update for new state

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have created a user interface to control lights, including a slider for brightness. It works pretty much as expected. But now I have added buttons for in/decrease brightness by 10%. It works as in the lights are dimmed accordingly, also the state is updated and the body method is called, and as the print output in LightsCell's body reveals, it is called with the correct values, but the slider isn't updated accordingly.

What am I missing? Thanks

The full codes: https://gitlab.com/vikingosegundo/brighter-hue

[image: video]

```swift
import SwiftUI

final class ViewState: ObservableObject  {
    
    @Published var lights : [ Light ] = []
    @Published var rooms  : [ Room  ] = []

    init(store: Store) {
        store.updated { self.process(state(of: store)) }
        process(state(of: store))
    }
    
    func handle(msg: Message) { }
    
    private func process(_ appState: AppState) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.lights = appState.lights.sorted(on:\.name, by:<)
            self.rooms = appState.rooms.sorted(on:\.title, by:<)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    init(viewState: ViewState, rootHandler: @escaping (Message) -> ()) {
        self.viewState = viewState
        self.rootHandler = rootHandler
    }
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewState: ViewState
    private let rootHandler: (Message) -> ()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Dashboard(rootHandler)
            Lights   (rootHandler)
            Rooms    (rootHandler)
            Shop     (rootHandler)
            Settings (rootHandler)
        }.environmentObject(viewState)
    }
}

struct Lights: View {
    init(_ rootHandler: @escaping (Message) -> ()) {
        self.rootHandler = rootHandler
    }
    
    @EnvironmentObject
    private var viewState: ViewState
    private let rootHandler: (Message) -> ()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(viewState.lights) { LightCell(light: $0, rootHandler:rootHandler) }
                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()).navigationTitle("Lights")
            }
        }.tabItem {
            Label("Lights", systemImage: "lightbulb")
        }
    }
}

struct LightCell: View {
    init(light: Light, rootHandler: @escaping (Message) -> ()) {
        self.rootHandler = rootHandler
        self.light = light
        self.isOn  = light.isOn
        self.hue   = light.hue
        self.sat   = light.saturation
        self.bri   = light.brightness
        self.ct    = Double(-light.ct)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        print("\(light.name) \(light.id): \(light.brightness)")
        return VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("\(light.name)").bold().dynamicTypeSize(.xLarge).fixedSize()
                Spacer()
                Toggle("", isOn: $isOn)
                    .onChange(of: isOn) { _ in
                        switch (light.isOn, isOn) {
                        case (true, false): rootHandler(.lighting(.turn(light,.off)))
                        case (false, true): rootHandler(.lighting(.turn(light,.on )))
                        case (  _  ,  _  ): ()
                        }
                    }
            }
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Picker("", selection: $_displayStyle) {
                    Image(systemName: "thermometer").tag(0)
                    Image(systemName: "paintpalette").tag(1)
                }.pickerStyle(.segmented).fixedSize()
                Spacer()
            }
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.fixed(80)), GridItem(.flexible())], alignment: .trailing) {
                switch displayStyle(for: _displayStyle) {
                case .hsb:
                    Text("Hue"       ).dynamicTypeSize(.xSmall);  Slider(value: $hue) { _ in rootHandler( .lighting(.set(.values(.hsb(hue,sat,bri), on:light))) ) }
                    Text("Saturation").dynamicTypeSize(.xSmall);  Slider(value: $sat) { _ in rootHandler( .lighting(.set(.values(.hsb(hue,sat,bri), on:light))) ) }
                case .ct:
                    Text("Color Temp").dynamicTypeSize(.xSmall).minimumScaleFactor(0.5);  Slider(value: $ct, in: (-500)...(-153)) { _ in rootHandler( .lighting(.set(.values(.ct(Int(-ct),bri), on:light))) ) }
                }
                Text("Brightness").dynamicTypeSize(.xSmall); HStack {
                    Button("-")         {      rootHandler( .lighting( .decrease(.brightness, by:.percent(10), on:light )) ) }
                    Slider(value: $bri) { _ in rootHandler( .lighting( .set(.values(.bri(bri),                 on:light))) ) }
                    Button("+")         {      rootHandler( .lighting( .increase(.brightness, by:.percent(10), on:light )) ) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private let light      : Light
    private let rootHandler: (Message) -> ()
    @State private var isOn : Bool
    @State private var hue : Double
    @State private var sat : Double
    @State private var bri : Double
    @State private var ct  : Double
    
    @State private var _displayStyle: Int = 0
}

extension LightCell {
    fileprivate enum DisplayStyle: Int, Hashable {
        case hsb
        case ct
    }
    
    private func selected(_ style: DisplayStyle)  {
        _displayStyle = number(for: style)
        print("\(style) selected for \(light.name)")
    }
}

private
func displayStyle(for x:Int) -> LightCell.DisplayStyle {
    switch x {
    case 0: return .ct
    case 1: return .hsb
    default: return .ct
    }
}

private
func number(for x:LightCell.DisplayStyle) -> Int {
    switch x {
    case .ct : return 0
    case .hsb: return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Slider` clearly modifies the `@State` variable `$bri`, but it is not clear to me that the `rootHandler` attached to the `Button` does the same. Have you used the debugger to trace the path to see if it's modifying it where you think it is?

Comment: this architecture follows a strict unidirectional flow pattern, including being fully immutable. so modification isn't really a thing, also the paths are very limited. basically there is just one. if you want to learn more about this architecture, I gave a presentation recently: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-WckUhhhII&list=PLY5suVncE-vfIoYDOLWggSOk0VtVcF7Tl&index=6&t=1285s

Comment: Okay — but this did end up being the issue (that bri wasn’t being modified), right?

Comment: the issue was that it was modified in body, I saw it being set in .init. but I had to declare it, as shown in the accepted answer. must be the magical state handling. it was modified and it wasn't. Schrödingers Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to update `$bri` var on button click.
You need this because there is no relation/ connection between slider and button.

```
Text("Brightness"); HStack {
    Button("-") {
        rootHandler( .lighting( .decrease(.brightness, by:.percent(10), on:light )) )
        bri = light.brightness //<-- Here
    }
    Slider(value: $bri) { _ in rootHandler( .lighting( .set(.values(.bri(bri),                 on:light))) ) }
    Button("+") {
        rootHandler( .lighting( .increase(.brightness, by:.percent(10), on:light )) )
        bri = light.brightness //<-- Here
    }
}
```

Or you can use this too

```
Text("Brightness"); HStack {
    // HStack Code
}
.onChange(of: light.brightness, perform: { value in
    bri = value //<-- Here
})
```

Note: I removed extra code as I'm using old Xcode.

Comment: feeling like an idiot in 3..2..1.. Thanks! I have lost days over this.

Comment: The second solution is the better on, as when I use the first solution in my code the slider is one tap behind if I use the buttons. This might be due to the fact that I am using a unidirectional flow pattern and there-for do not fully use binding as expected. Anyway: the second solution works great.